# Connection with Gmail SMTP cannot be established whith my php script

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I want to make just a basic email sending script. Because I want to run it on localhost I use Gmail SMTP. I have both enabled IMAP settings and I allowed access from less secure apps. Surprisingly, I still cannot connect. Everytime I try, I get the error `SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting`

Why is that happening? I am using this code:

```
   <?php

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = "First email";
    $txt = "Do you want our service?";


    //require_once('PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php');
    require_once "PHPMailer\PHPMailer.php";
    require_once "PHPMailer\SMTP.php";
    require_once "PHPMailer\Exception.php";


    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->isHTML();
    $mail->Username = "myemailnotimportant@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "password123";
    $mail->SetFrom('myemailnotimportant@gmail.com', 'Sir Walter Scott');
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $txt;
    $mail->AddAddress($to);


       if ($mail->Send()) {
       echo "email sent";
       } else {

           echo "Something is wrong: <br><br>" . $mail->ErrorInfo;

       }



    }
    ?>
```

Comment: From your github link : This is often reported as a PHPMailer problem, but it's almost always down to local DNS failure, firewall blocking (for example as GoDaddy does) or another issue on your local network. It means that PHPMailer is unable to contact the SMTP server you have specified in the Host property, but doesn't say exactly why. It can also be caused by not having the openssl extension loaded (See encryption notes below).

Comment: So what is the solution to this? I use xampp Apache (not GoDaddy).

Comment: I would try to change `SMTPSecure` to `tls` and `Port` to `587`. AFAIK ssl can work but sometimes it gets blocked since ssl is basically deprecated in favor of tls.

Comment: It's nothing to do with whether you're using XAMPP or apache, but whether your ISP blocks outbound SMTP, which is very common. The tests in the troubleshooting guide will help you diagnose the problem.